# Office JS - deleting a content control issue

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I'm trying to delete a content control in Word and I'm going through these docs: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/contentcontrol

This is my code:

```
let mycc = context.document.contentControls.getByTag('mycc');
if (mycc) {
    context.load(mycc, 'text');
    context.sync().then(() => {
        mycc.items[0].delete(true);
        context.sync().then(() => { ... })
    })
}
```

No error is thrown and the code inside the inner most sync works (inserting another content control).

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Found the issue. The content control was indeed being deleted, but I wanted to delete the content, as well. Instead of passing `true` to `delete`, I should have passed `false`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unable to reproduce the issue that you've described. Given that the code that you've posted does not include any error-handling logic, I'd suspect that perhaps an error is silently being thrown, but you're not detecting it.

The following code snippet successfully deletes the first content control that has the tag **mycc**, and includes a `catch` statement that handles any error which might occur inside of the `Word.run`.

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    var myContentControls = context.document.contentControls.getByTag("mycc");
    if (myContentControls) {
        context.load(myContentControls, "text");
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                myContentControls.items[0].delete(true);
                return context.sync()
                    .then(function () {
                        console.log("Done!");
                    });
            });
    }
}).catch(OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log);
```

Comment: I do have `catch` statements (omitted from my code snippet above), but there is no error thrown. The code in the inner most context.sync(), illustrated with `...` runs ok.

Comment: Scratch that, actually. Just found the issue, please see my edit above. I've upvoted your answer because it's a complete working example (along with Word.run etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the update (and the upvote); happy to hear that you figured it out.